# SQL to filter by year

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql

I am unable to filter by year in SQL.

This is my SQL:

```
SELECT
c.Organisation__c,
DATEPART(year, s.ContractYear__c) AS ContractYear__c
FROM ....

WHERE DATEPART(year, s.ContractYear__c) = '2020'
```

and it's pulling all records, I can see various years in the ContractYear__c column:

[image]

How to correctly filter by year?
Thank you

Comment: What's the datatype of the `ContractYear__c` column?

Comment: It's Date datatype

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about if you use the year() function and compare it to a number?

```sql
SELECT
c.Organisation__c,
year(s.ContractYear__c) as ContractYear__c
FROM ....
WHERE year(s.ContractYear__c) = 2020
```

Comment: the result is the same as with DATEPART, still doesn't filter the results by year

Comment: OK, I noticed that it's working when I do `WHERE year(s.ContractYear__c) = 2020
 AND c.Email IS NOT NULL` but it don't work when I do `WHERE c.Email IS NOT NULL AND year(s.ContractYear__c) = 2020`

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the problem is in `= '2020'`. `DATEPART` function returns an integer, so it is better to compare to `= 2020`.

`YEAR` function by itself shouldn't change anything as it is just wrapper on `DATEPART(YEAR, X)`.

This should work:

```sql
SELECT
    c.Organisation__c,
    DATEPART(YEAR, s.ContractYear__c) AS ContractYear__c
FROM ....
WHERE DATEPART(YEAR, s.ContractYear__c) = 2020
```

However, I also tested it with a string date on my instance and it was working correctly for the `DateJoined` field of `_Subscribers` data view.

Are you testing the query with Query Studio or SQL Query Activity? If the latter, are you cleaning the Data Extension between tests? Maybe those are records from previous runs with the new ones being added/updated?

Comment: I tried with `'2020'` and with `2020` and it still doesn't filter correctly